# UnsupportedOperationException for updateItem Date attribute in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update one date attribute of an item in dynamodb by following piece of  code:

```
     AttributeUpdate attributeUpdates = new AttributeUpdate("workDate");
     Date workDate = finalMap.get(tID);
     attributeUpdates.put(workDate);
     PrimaryKey primaryKey = new PrimaryKey("tID", tID);
     UpdateItemOutcome outcome =  table.updateItem(primaryKey, attributeUpdates);
```

Last line, where I am calling table.updateItem, is giving UnSupportedOperationException as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: value type: class java.util.Date
```

Does anyone have any clue regarding how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB does not accept dates as a [data type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes). You will need to convert that date into a string, then do the update.

Comment: Similarly, I tried to store an enum value into an attribute of type String, and I got UnsupportedOperationException.  I needed to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate easy date-handling, try saving the long integer millisecond time represented by the Date object:

```
Date workDate = finalMap.get(tID);
attributeUpdates.put(workDate.getTime());
```

This can be easily and unambiguously translated back to a Date object when you load the record, by using
`new Date(long Date)`